# Reading data from serial port using C++/Visual Studio

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm running Windows 7 and using Visual Studio 2012 RC. I have a USB device connected to my COM6 port, and the device is streaming ASCII output. I want to grab that data to use in my program, which I'm writing in C++. I'm pretty new to programming in general, so I'm sort of lost. I know I have to use a certain library, and I saw the function CreateFile being used, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be much obliged, thank you.

Edit: I'm able to open the port and retrieve its basic data: I can print out the baud rate, bit size, parity, and stop bits values. But I need to retrieve the streaming ASCII data, which is where I'm lost. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: What did you try? Note that the device name is written like this: `CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM6", ...`. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831)

Comment: BTW, if you're new to programming, I would not start with these kind of things, you'll need to start a thread, use ReadFile, parse ASCII lines, and synchronize between other threads. This is not a "Hello World" we're talking about :)

Comment: I'm able to open the port and read its settings - I can see the baudrate, bytesize, parity, and stopbits values. I just need to see the ASCII data it's suppose to be streaming now.

Comment: Yes, they still exist in the form of USB-to-Serial converters that use virtual COM ports: http://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-RS-232-Serial-Converter-TU-S9/dp/B0007T27H8

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm using. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

Serial_Port.h: http://pastebin.com/Hft1zYS3

Serial_Port.cpp: http://pastebin.com/ZzfUujNY

Comment: I tried using this. I get this error: 1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afx.h(24): fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

So I googled the error and followed instrunctions. I went to Use of MFC in properties and selected "USE MFC in Static Library." I then got a LNK1120 error. Googled it, still unresolved. Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to build. But I get this error at run-time:  Googled it, fixed it, got it to build... but at runtime, I get this: Unhandled exception at 0x01BFF782 in serialPort.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Below is a snippet of code that opens the port (COM3) and writes a string to it. Sorry, no snippet on reading the port, but reading from the port, but that should be trivial. 

http://pastebin.com/bhkRbca3

Comment: I suspect you aren't opening the port correctly because you aren't specifying the correct COM port number.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be a step in the right direction for me. Using that snippet, however, there seems to be an error with stop_tlm_msg.GetBuffer(); Says that LPWSTR cannot be used to initialize an entity of type *char.

Comment: You could try this instead: `char sBuf1[] = "whateveryouwanttowrite";` instead of `char * sBuf1 = stop_tlm_msg.GetBuffer();`

Comment: It would be cool if you accepted my answer. The code I gave you is tested and works.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my second time using stack overflow and I'm not really sure how to do things on it quite yet. I tried to upvote your answer, but it said I needed 15 reputation. Is there anything else I can do to approve it?

Comment: Cool! Thanks man. Post more comments here if you still haven't gotten it to work and I'll help you along.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a complete library that is well tested. Here is the one I use:

http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-activex/